# During debugging how to inspect value for any extended table field?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

In VS during debugging, adding a watch will not see the value properly if the object is an extended table field. Currently, I have to open up a field called Extension_fields from the related table in order to see the extended field's value and the field name after adding to watch is a mess. Is there any better way?

Comment: Can you please put screen shot of what you see and what is mess on same?

Comment: Sorry I am not currently working in that project. Just put a watch on any extended table field you create and you will see the same result.